# How to transform Xml to hierarchical Xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have this XML file and want to perform an Xslt 2.0 Transformation.

The Problem is, that the the nodes are at the same Level and reference to each other with ID's, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Data id = "1" referenceID = "2 3">
    Text1
</Data>

<Data id = "2" referenceID = "4">
    Text2
</Data>

<Data id = "3" referenceID = "5">
    Text3
</Data>

<Data id = "4">
    Text4
</Data>

<Data id = "5">
    Text5
</Data>
```

The desired Output should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Level1>
    Text1
    <Level2>
        Text2
        <Level3>
            Text4
        </Level3>
    </Level2>

    <Level2>
        Text3
        <Level3>
            Text5
        </Level3>
    </Level2>
</Level1>
```

I already tried to use templates and call them recursively but with no success.
Maybe there is a easy way to tackle this kind of problem.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a common container element for the `Data` elements? And what determines which element(s) form the first level of the nested output, is that simply the order or do you need to check which elements are not referenced by others?

Comment: Thank you for your input Martin! Excuse me for the inaccurate description. I have given, that the top level ID is "1" and all referrenced ID's are children of this one. So one has to follow all the reference ID's.

There is a common Container for the data elements but I can't see how this Container could help me with the Transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a key to identify `Data` elements by the `id` attribute and then follow references using the `key` function on the `tokenize(@referenceID, '\s+')` sequence:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="ref" match="Data" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[Data[@id]]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', '1')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
      <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer" select="1"/>
      <xsl:element name="Level{$level}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), key('ref', tokenize(@referenceID, '\s+'))">
              <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That gives the right structure http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMek/2, identation with mixed contents is difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Does this Approach also work if the starting ID would not be "1" or a starting id given as string like "id2"?
For example if also the ID's would reference like "id2" references to "id5" and "id5" references to "id11" for example.

Comment: The key works with any values used in the input XML as the `id` attribute. Of course you need to change the `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', '1')"/>` to use whatever value you have e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', 'id2')"/>`. If you need to make that a parameter you can declare a global (top-level) `<xsl:param name="starting-id" as="xs:string" select="'id2'"/>` and then change the line to `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', $starting-id)"/>`. A global parameter can then be set when you run the transformation (e.g. from the command line or using the API or your IDE).

Comment: Thank you Martin! I used your advice with the global variable and was able to achieve the desired output! 
Indentation worked for me by using:
`<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></xsl:template>`
and
`<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`